# How to return or cast the same type from web services

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I've created a web service in asp.net (ASMX) for caching purposes.
The website that uses this WS, requests and gets a shared type object (that is, both the website & webservices use the same DLL that includes that object type).

but what happens is, that the website gets the response from the webservices and the type is being wrapped by the WS's name space.

for instance.
If I have in the shared DLL a class Core.Person
the webservice returns Core.Person.
the website (even it knows the core.person) will get WebServiceNS.Person

This won't allow me to cast it.

how can I still use the same original DLL namespace when getting those objects from the WS?

thanks

Comment: How are you adding objects to cache? You might be over writing the old objects. Post the code in which you add objects to cache.

Comment: HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(cacheKey, new Core.Person(10), null, DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
                            System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

Comment: @AmarPalsapure - i dont see how it is related to the cache

Comment: Sorry got it wrong. Will post one solution.

Comment: You have `Person` class in a `Core` namespace and you are referring this DLL in both website and webservice. Right? And in webservice you are adding `Person` from `Core.dll`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using ASMX services for new development. It's a legacy technology.

In addition, it has no ability to do what you want. WCF, on the other hand, can do it trivially.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be, instead of using ASMX service use WCF service. WCF service allows you to use existing structure for the webservice call. In that case you will not need to create reference of your service. You can use same `Core.dll` in both the projects.

If you need any help in this, post a comment.

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we add a webservice reference VS generates a stub creating classes for all the objects required by WS. (These are on the basis of WSDL file hosted on the web server). All our communication with the webservice is done using this stub. I guess you'll have to write your own [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this.

Comment: Seems combersome... there must be a way to at least be able to cast it to the original type...

Comment: There are some "unrecommended" ways available though. (http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/26/737.aspx) In the later paragraphs you can see the pros/cons of this technique.